# webpack not showing font-awesome icons (only empty squares)

Tags: angular, webpack, font-awesome

I use angular 6 with webpack 4 module bundler. I have searched a lot on how to load font-awesome combined with webpack, but only empty square are displayed.

Font-awesome is installed through npm (npm install font-awesome) (version 4.7.0).

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
  [{
      {
                test: /\.(eot|woff(2)?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: "fonts/"                               
                        }
                    }]
            }
  }]
}
```

font-awesome.scss

```
$fa-font-path: '~font-awesome/fonts';
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

font-awesome.scss is imported inside my base module file. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same in my angular 6 project I resolved it by below way.

Add these dependencies rather font-awesome. these are core and there is a package for angular as well.

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-9",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.0-11",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
```

Now add font awesome to you module as import as below. This is the fontawesome-angular provided by font-awesome team.

```
FontAwesomeModule
```

Now add the icons you need in component and use them in the html below way.

component class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  faUtensils,
  faGlassMartini,
  faTruckMoving,
  faWineGlass,
  faCoffee,
  faShoppingCart,
  faGamepad,
  faBirthdayCake,
  faBeer,
  faStar,
  faStarHalf, faMagic, faSquare
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

@Component({
  selector: 'xxxx',
  templateUrl: './xxx.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xxx.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
  ) {
    library.add(
      faUtensils,
      faGlassMartini,
      faTruckMoving,
      faCoffee,
      faWineGlass,
      faShoppingCart,
      faGamepad,
      faBirthdayCake,
      faBeer,
      faStar,
      faStarHalf,
      faMagic,
      faSquare
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And then in your html just use these icons

```
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'beer']" [size]="'2x'"
               [styles]="{color:'#F36F24'}"></fa-icon>
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'glass-martini']" [size]="'2x'"
               [styles]="{color:'#F36F24'}"></fa-icon>
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'truck-moving']" [size]="'2x'"
               [styles]="{color:'#F36F24'}"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: Do you have webpack in your project?

Comment: I am using angular cli which is using webpack internally. so angular cli will build and do everything using webpack. Are you not using angular cli?

Comment: I am not using angular cli, but custom webpack configuration from cratch. I will give your suggested answer a try and i will inform you if everything is ok.

Comment: It is working with @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-10 version...but when i use the latest version 0.1.0 i get 'unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module'...

Comment: I will try the latest version `0.1.0` . might be it will be a small fix. it should work i think